How do I set user Profile using add_argument?
I try to launch Chrome with my Profile, but it doesn't open the profile. (User 1, the login has not been completed in Browser window)
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--user_data_dir=C:\\Users\\shulya403\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")

self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

Other Chrome window - closed, the only browser Chrome window - is opened by WebDriver.
The path
C:\\Users\\shulya403\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default

exists in the system.
Other options (window-size and others) are working properly.

--user_data_dir is an invalid argument and should be --user-data-dir (see documentation )
Besides that, you might as well want to normalize that path to use / instead of \\.
The line should look about as followig:
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/shulya403/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")

Also note that --profile-directory=Default

might not be necessary (or even break smth) 
or
should be --profile-directory=User 1 instead

